# Amount of time permitted to fill in DS-260 form for USA spouse visa

Tags: usa, visa

I'm a UK citizen in the process of applying for a spouse visa to immigrate to the USA. It has been approved in principle, and I'm currently filling in my DS-260 form. My question is: is there a time limit for how long I have to complete this form? It has become apparent that for work-related reasons I will be staying in the UK for another year or so. It's already been 6 months since my visa was approved in principle.

Comment: By "my visa was approved in principle" do you mean your spouse's petition for you to immigrate (I-130) was approved?

Comment: OP has not returned to clarify, putting on hold.

Comment: It seems now that the expiry date for this is published on the ds-260 form website.